# How to use state dropdown and city dropdown javascript multiple time without affecting other dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am using CodeIgniter, I have four select country dropdown and depending upon the country, the state will display in the next dropdown, once state select then the city will display in the next select dropdown.

view

```
<!--country-->
    <select  class="form_control country_change" name="c_country">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select Country</option>
         <?php foreach ($get_country as $row) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->country_name;?></option>
        <?php }?>
     </select>

    <!--state-->
     <select  class="form_control state_get" name="c_state">
      <option value='' disabled selected>Select state</option>
     </select>

    <!--city-->
     <select  class="form_control city_get" name="c_city">
     <option value="">Select city </option>
     </select>
```

I have above same HTML code 3 times more with different `name`

Custom.js

```
/*Get all the state name using country code*/
   $(".country_change").on('change',function(){
      var country_id=$(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo site_url('Customer_control/statename');?>",
      method:"POST",
      data:"country_id="+country_id,
     dataType: "json",
      success:function(data){
        $('.state_get').empty();
        var placeholder="<option value='' disabled selected>Select state</option>";
        $('.state_get').html(placeholder);
            $.each(data, function(i, data) {
          $('.state_get').append("<option value='" + data.id + "'>" + data.state_name + "</option>");
            });
      }
     });
  });
   /*Get all the city name using state code*/
   $(".state_get").on('change',function(){
      var state_id=$(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      url:"<?php echo site_url('Customer_control/cityname');?>",
      method:"POST",
      data:"state_id="+state_id,
      dataType: "json",
      success:function(data){
        $('.city_get').empty();
        var placeholder="<option value='' disabled selected>Select city</option>";
        $('.city_get').html(placeholder);
        $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        $('.city_get').append("<option value='" + data.id + "'>" + data.cities_name + "</option>");
            });
      }

     });
  });
```

Above process is perfectly working for me. I am able to display the city depending upon state name and state depending upon the country.

Now My concern is, I have to use the same script for the rest of the 3 drops down. I don't want to use extra javascript. So how can I use the same script multiple times without effect on another dropdown?

Hope you understand my issue. Would you help me out in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use id attribute on each dropdown, and in your script refer which dropdown you want to fill with the response data. I leave you one example:

**HTML:**

```
<select  class="form_control country_change" name="c_country" data-target="dropdown_state_one">
<option value="" disabled selected>Select Country</option>
 <?php foreach ($get_country as $row) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->country_name;?></option>
<?php }?>
```

```
<select  class="form_control state_get" name="c_state" id="dropdown_state_one">
<option value='' disabled selected>Select state</option>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(".country_change").on('change',function(){
        var country_id = $(this).val(),
            state_list = $(this).data('target'); // The dropdown ID
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo site_url('Customer_control/statename');?>",
            method:"POST",
            data:"country_id="+country_id,
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(data){
                $('#'+state_list).empty();
                var placeholder="<option value='' disabled selected>Select state</option>";
                $('#'+state_list).html(placeholder);
                $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                    $('#'+state_list).append("<option value='" + data.id + "'>" + data.state_name + "</option>");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I hope that help you!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you share the HTML as well, What Id I have to use it in HTML?

Comment: I edited my answer with the html, and you can use anything like id.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again, Give me some time to implement this.

Comment: There is some issue, I added id="dropdown_list_one" to the first country drop down(according to your code).save it and refresh the page for the testing and I choose United State in the dropdown but I am not getting the output in the state dropdown. I am getting the output in the same country dropdown.

Comment: Yes, It's working for the country, What about choose state name and display the city name in the drop-down?

Comment: You can do the same, add to the state dropdown a data-target property, for example data-target="dropdown_city_one"; and in the dropdown city add the id="dropdown_city_one".

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly. Thanks upvote from my side